# VS Ordered Tests with Selenium WebDriver won't continue after first test due to ChomeDriver closing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, selenium, testing

So I have setup an automation framework and for each test that I want to run, I have created their own Unit Test. During our smoke test, we run through several of the Unit Tests that I've built in order. Therefor, I figured it would be a good idea to create an Ordered Test. When running each test individually, they work just fine. However, once I start running the Ordered Tests, the first test in the list will run, but then I get this error:

**OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException: Unexpected error. System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it**

I have tracked this problem to be caused because the ChromeDriver is closing at the end of the first test. However, even if I tell it not to close the driver, it seems to close it. If I tell the [SetUp] of each Unit Test to create a new driver, it doesn't seem to work either.

I have setup the code like this for now:

```
public static IWebDriver getWebDriver()
{
    IWebDriver newDriver = new ChromeDriver(@"..\..\..\packages\Selenium.Chrome.WebDriver.2.33\driver");

    return newDriver;
}

public static IWebDriver webDriver;
```

Then from the Unit Tests I'm setting the webDriver = getWebDriver() which should cause it to create a new one. I have also tried creating multiple [TestMethod] in a single Unit Test, but it still ends up giving me the same error. I'm really at a loss about what I should be doing at this point and am fairly new with no peers to guide me at work. Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar errors. At first I believed that the error was with the chromedriver but after many hours of investigation I discovered that when I saw this error is was one of 2 things:

1. Chrome version vs chromedriver version vs selenium version.
   So the first thing (which you've probably already done) is to make sure you have the latest and greatest versions of the nuget packages. (Chrome of course takes care of it's own updates--which is usually what causes the problem).
2. Carefully look at your code and make sure you have an application level "Try Catch". [This article from Microsoft should help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3.aspx).

What I found in my own code was what looked like a chromedriver issue was really an issue with timing when moving from one page to another. Now I have methods to verify I'm on the right page and have methods that verify page elements exist before I attempt to use them. I end up writing a lot of:

```
 if (driver.PageSource.Contains("Some text that means the page is loaded"))
```

I also add a small amount of wait time behind each interaction of the page which can take time. You'll want to make sure every element you use exists before you attempt to use it. I do that like this:

```
 if (IsElementDisplayed(driver, By.XPath(Settings.Default.X_GenerateButton)))
 {
      //click the generate button
      driver.FindElement(By.XPath(Settings.Default.X_GenerateButton)).Click();

      //wait for a couple of seconds
      Thread.Sleep(2000);

 }
```

Here's what my IsElementDisplayed method looks like:

```
 public bool IsElementDisplayed(IWebDriver driver, By element)
 {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                IReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> elements = driver.FindElements(element);
                if (elements.Count > 0)
                {
                    return elements.ElementAt(0).Displayed;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception was raised on locating element: " + e.Message);
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        return false;
 }
```

Hope this helps, good luck tracking down the issue.